# What is the benefit of online play in Ratchet & Clank: All 4 One?

Tags: ratchet-and-clank-all-4-one

I was diving into the single player today and I imagine it plays much like the multiplayer experience. Other than playing with other living souls is there a benefit to playing through the game multiplayer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

2 trophies and someone to help you get through the harder stuff should he have more weapons and knows the route/hero bolt locations/secret labs